# Connecting 2 servers via Node Websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have 2 Raspberry Pi running on the same Network.

I am using one as a local web server for my house, I then have another one connected to some devices. I want them to both be able to communicate to each other via web sockets but am having some problems.

My server looks like this:

```
express = require('express');  //web server
app = express();
server = require('http').createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);   //web socket server

server.listen(8080); //start the webserver on port 8080
app.use(express.static('public')); //tell the server that ./public/ contains the static webpages

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { //gets called whenever a client connects
    socket.on('Testing',function(data){
       console.log("Testing connection");
    });    
});
```

My problem comes with the client connection I am really not sure what code to use to try and connect.

I have installed Express and Socket.io on my client and used this code:

```
    console.log('1');

   // Connect to server
var io = require('socket.io')
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.138:8080', {reconnect: true});

console.log('2');

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function(socket) { 
    console.log('Connected!');
});

console.log('3');
```

But this leads to an error on the io.connect is not a function.

I am not really sure how to get the client to work so any advice is appreciated.

I should add that connecting to my webserver directly via the ip and port does load the webpages I have created successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using socket.io on the server side as a client you need to do `var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.1.138:8080', ...);`.  See [https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client](http://here)